# A "significant" solid with volume $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\pi r^3$?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, volume

In a painting:

there is this formula of volume:

$$V = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\pi r^3$$

It seems to me this is the formula of the volume of some polyhedron inscribed or circumscribed to a sphere of radius $r$, but I am not expert of the field.

I had the task of finding the meaning of the different formulas, that were taken from a web site whose address has been lost, so I need to find the regular solid that corresponds to such formula, if it exists.

So I am asking help from somebody more expert then me in the field of geometry of solids, if there is some "significant" solid with the volume given by that formula.

Note: this question is twin of [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3530593/is-there-a-significant-solid-with-volume-frac157-sqrt512-cdot-l3).

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I think this question needs to be reformulated in order not to be closed. The solid could be anything. For example, any cone with a circular base of radius $r$ and height $\sqrt{3} r$ (e.g. upright cone with base angle $\pi/3$) will do.

Comment: The appearance of $\pi$ suggests that this is not the formula for the volume of a (flat-sided) polyhedron, whether inscribed or circumscribed about a sphere. Rather, there must be a circular component. @LeeDavidChungLin's suggestion —a cone of radius $r$ and height $\sqrt{3}r$— seems to be the "most natural" one to me. (The desired volume is $\frac13\cdot \pi r^2\cdot \sqrt{3} r$; ie, $\frac13\cdot(\text{area of base})\cdot(\text{height})$.) I'll note that such a cone arises from revolving an equilateral triangle of side $2r$ about an axis of symmetry.

Comment: Why are you not stating the webpage? What is there to hide?

Comment: You asked this question just last week, not months ago. Why should you be interested in a formula on a webpage that you forgot?

Comment: That context is relevant, and if you have a image of or link to the painting, it should go into your question. Otherwise there is no motivation at all for your question, which would be of almost no value to other readers.

Comment: Next time, include such information in your questions. I've done it for you here. Please edit your other question to include the same information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Converting a comment to an answer, as requested.)

The appearance of $\pi$ suggests that this is not the formula for the volume of a (flat-sided, straight-edged) polyhedron, whether inscribed or circumscribed about a sphere. Rather, there must be a circular component.

@LeeDavidChungLin's commented suggestion ---a cone of radius $r$ and height $\sqrt{3}\,r$--- seems to be the "most natural" one: the target volume decomposes as
$$\frac13\cdot \pi r^2 \cdot \sqrt{3}\,r \;=\; \frac13\cdot(\text{area of base})\cdot(\text{height})$$

I'll note that such a cone arises from revolving an equilateral triangle of side $2r$ about an axis of symmetry.